# NewTek NDI (SDK v5) with Qt6.3: How to display NDI video frames on the GUI?

Tags: qt, user-interface, video, stream, sdk

I have integrated the NDI SDK from NewTek in the current version 5 into my Qt6.3 widget project.
I copied and included the required DLLs and header files from the NDI SDK installation directory into my project.

To test my build environment I tried to compile a simple test program based on the example from "..\NDI 5 SDK\Examples\C++\NDIlib_Recv".
That was also successful.
I was therefore able to receive or access data from my NDI source.

There is therefore a valid frame in the video_frame of the type NDIlib_video_frame_v2_t. Within the structure I can also query correct data of the frame such as the size (.xres and .yres).
The pointer p_data points to the actual data.

So far so good.

Of course, I now want to display this frame on the Qt6 GUI. In other words, the only thing missing now is the conversion into an appropriate format so that I can display the frame with QImage, QPixmap, QLabel, etc.
But how?

So far I've tried calls like this:

```
curFrame = QImage(video_frame.p_data, video_frame.xres, video_frame.yres, QImage::Format::Format_RGB888);
curFrame.save("out.jpg");
```

I'm not sure if the format is correct either.
Here's a closer look at the mentioned frame structure within the Qt debug session:

[my NDI video frame in the Qt Debug session, after receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnLEm.gif)

Within "video_frame" you can see the specification **video_type_UYVY**.
This may really be the format as it appears at the source!?

**Fine, but how do I get this converted now?**

Many thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this? :)
https://github.com/NightVsKnight/QtNdiMonitorCapture

Specifically:
https://github.com/NightVsKnight/QtNdiMonitorCapture/blob/main/lib/ndireceiverworker.cpp

Assuming you connect using `NDIlib_recv_color_format_best`:

```cpp
NDIlib_recv_create_v3_t recv_desc;
recv_desc.p_ndi_recv_name = "QtNdiMonitorCapture";
recv_desc.source_to_connect_to = ...;
recv_desc.color_format = NDIlib_recv_color_format_best;
recv_desc.bandwidth = NDIlib_recv_bandwidth_highest;
recv_desc.allow_video_fields = true;
pNdiRecv = NDIlib_recv_create_v3(&recv_desc);
```

Then when you receive a `NDIlib_video_frame_v2_t`:

```cpp
void NdiReceiverWorker::processVideo(
        NDIlib_video_frame_v2_t *pNdiVideoFrame,
        QList<QVideoSink*> *videoSinks)
{
    auto ndiWidth = pNdiVideoFrame->xres;
    auto ndiHeight = pNdiVideoFrame->yres;
    auto ndiLineStrideInBytes = pNdiVideoFrame->line_stride_in_bytes;
    auto ndiPixelFormat = pNdiVideoFrame->FourCC;
    auto pixelFormat = NdiWrapper::ndiPixelFormatToPixelFormat(ndiPixelFormat);
    if (pixelFormat == QVideoFrameFormat::PixelFormat::Format_Invalid)
    {
        qDebug().nospace() << "Unsupported pNdiVideoFrame->FourCC " << NdiWrapper::ndiFourCCToString(ndiPixelFormat) << "; return;";
        return;
    }

    QSize videoFrameSize(ndiWidth, ndiHeight);
    QVideoFrameFormat videoFrameFormat(videoFrameSize, pixelFormat);
    QVideoFrame videoFrame(videoFrameFormat);

    if (!videoFrame.map(QVideoFrame::WriteOnly))
    {
        qWarning() << "videoFrame.map(QVideoFrame::WriteOnly) failed; return;";
        return;
    }

    auto pDstY = videoFrame.bits(0);
    auto pSrcY = pNdiVideoFrame->p_data;
    auto pDstUV = videoFrame.bits(1);
    auto pSrcUV = pSrcY + (ndiLineStrideInBytes * ndiHeight);
    for (int line = 0; line < ndiHeight; ++line)
    {
        memcpy(pDstY, pSrcY, ndiLineStrideInBytes);
        pDstY += ndiLineStrideInBytes;
        pSrcY += ndiLineStrideInBytes;

        if (pDstUV)
        {
            // For now QVideoFrameFormat/QVideoFrame does not support P216. :(
            // I have started the conversation to have it added, but that may take awhile. :(
            // Until then, copying only every other UV line is a cheap way to downsample P216's 4:2:2 to P016's 4:2:0 chroma sampling.
            // There are still a few visible artifacts on the screen, but it is passable.
            if (line % 2)
            {
                memcpy(pDstUV, pSrcUV, ndiLineStrideInBytes);
                pDstUV += ndiLineStrideInBytes;
            }
            pSrcUV += ndiLineStrideInBytes;
        }
    }

    videoFrame.unmap();

    foreach(QVideoSink *videoSink, *videoSinks)
    {
        videoSink->setVideoFrame(videoFrame);
    }
}
```

```cpp
QVideoFrameFormat::PixelFormat NdiWrapper::ndiPixelFormatToPixelFormat(enum NDIlib_FourCC_video_type_e ndiFourCC)
{
    switch(ndiFourCC)
    {
    case NDIlib_FourCC_video_type_UYVY:
        return QVideoFrameFormat::PixelFormat::Format_UYVY;
    case NDIlib_FourCC_video_type_UYVA:
        return QVideoFrameFormat::PixelFormat::Format_UYVY;
        break;
    // Result when requesting NDIlib_recv_color_format_best
    case NDIlib_FourCC_video_type_P216:
        return QVideoFrameFormat::PixelFormat::Format_P016;
    //case NDIlib_FourCC_video_type_PA16:
    //    return QVideoFrameFormat::PixelFormat::?;
    case NDIlib_FourCC_video_type_YV12:
        return QVideoFrameFormat::PixelFormat::Format_YV12;
    //case NDIlib_FourCC_video_type_I420:
    //    return QVideoFrameFormat::PixelFormat::?
    case NDIlib_FourCC_video_type_NV12:
        return QVideoFrameFormat::PixelFormat::Format_NV12;
    case NDIlib_FourCC_video_type_BGRA:
        return QVideoFrameFormat::PixelFormat::Format_BGRA8888;
    case NDIlib_FourCC_video_type_BGRX:
        return QVideoFrameFormat::PixelFormat::Format_BGRX8888;
    case NDIlib_FourCC_video_type_RGBA:
        return QVideoFrameFormat::PixelFormat::Format_RGBA8888;
    case NDIlib_FourCC_video_type_RGBX:
        return QVideoFrameFormat::PixelFormat::Format_RGBX8888;
    default:
        return QVideoFrameFormat::PixelFormat::Format_Invalid;
    }
}
```